# What is the best option to set and get HTTP headers?? Using Apache CXF interceptor or a Filter

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, cxf, etag

In one of my projects i have to set the **ETag** header in responses and read the **if-none-matched** header in the incoming requests. As of now i have implemented this using **Apache CXF Filters** however as i searched and found, the same functionality can be done by using **interceptors** as well. what are the significant advantages and/or disadvantages that i will have to experience if i proceed with CXF filters??

as of now i have implemented the filter and it works fine What would be the best practices in using a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quote from http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html.

> Difference between JAXRS filters and CXF interceptors
>   JAXRS runtime flow is mainly implemented by a pair of 'classical' CXF interceptors. JAXRSInInterceptor is currently at Phase.UNMARSHAL (was at Phase.PRE_STREAM before CXF 2.2.2) phase while JAXRSOutInterceptor is currently at Phase.MARSHAL phase.
>
> JAXRS filters can be thought of as additional handlers. JAXRSInInterceptor deals with a chain of Pre and Post Match ContainerRequestFilters, just before the invocation. JAXRSOutInterceptor deals with a chain of ContainerResponseFilters, just after the invocation but before message body writers get their chance.
>
> Sometimes you may want to use CXF interceptors rather than writing JAXRS filters. For example, suppose you combine JAXWS and JAXRS and you need to log only inbound or outbound messages. You can reuse the existing CXF interceptors :

```
<beans>
<bean id="logInbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
<bean id="logOutbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>

<jaxrs:server> 
  <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
    <ref bean="logInbound"/>
  </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
  <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
    <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
  </jaxrs:outInterceptors>
</jaxrs:server>
<jaxws:endpoint>
 <jaxws:inInterceptors>
 <ref bean="logInbound"/>
 </jaxws:inInterceptors>
 <jaxws:outInterceptors>
<ref bean="logOutbound"/>
 </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

> Reusing other CXF interceptors/features such as GZIP handlers can be useful too.
>
> At the moment it is not possible to override a response status code from a CXF interceptor running before JAXRSOutInterceptor, like CustomOutInterceptor above, which will be fixed.

Comment: thanks for the reply but what i really need is whether to continue using the filter or to make a new interceptor.. FYI in my case I have to add the etag header to a already created payload. and if the incoming request has the same etag then i have to respond to the client with a 304 saying that the resource is not modified. any comments on that??

Comment: I would carry on using your filter, and override the response properties.  Interceptors are powerful concepts when you want to alter the processing chain; however, they do not provide the capability of overriding a response status code (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html).

Comment: is there anything like phases found in interceptors which can be used in filters ?? cause i want this filter to come after the OAuthInterceptor for security concerns !

Comment: Have a look at CXF JAX-RS SimpleAuthorizingFilter.  This wraps up a number of authentication interceptors.  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/secure-jax-rs-services.html#SecureJAX-RSServices-Authorization

Comment: Has that answered your question? Is it worth marking it as answered?